# How can i print all possible order of an array with n integers using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

For example, if I have an array a=  {1, 2, 6, 10}, it should print all combinations of these 4 numbers, there should be 4! total combinations. An array of 5 integers will have a total of 5! combinations. (Different from previous versions because my number of parameters have to stay same. I am not allowed to put more than 3 paramrters in.

array a=  {1, 2, 6, 10}

{1, 2, 10, 6}

{1, 6, 2, 10}

{1, 6, 10, 2}

.

.

.

{10, 6, 2, 1}

I am trying to solve this process using Recursion, any idea how? this is the code i have for now. Can anyone who has any idea whats going on please help me?

```
static void permutations (int a[], int n, int p){
    if (p==n-1)
        return ;
    for (int i=p; i<n; i++){
        int b[]=new int [n];
        b[p]=a[i];
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            b[j]=a[j];
            for (int k =i+1; k<n; k++)
                b[k]=a[k];    
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
        return permutations(b, n, p+1);  
    }         
}
```

Comment: can there be duplicate numbers, and how should they be handeled ?

Comment: There are many examples of this on the Internet and several on Stack Overflow.  Search first, then post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion - Combination with in array with no repetition in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084420/recursion-combination-with-in-array-with-no-repetition-in-java)

Comment: No duplicate numbers. 
Also, I have tried other versions from stackoverflow, but this is the format I have been asked to use.

Answer (score 0):

best way to solve your problem to use Permutations concept in Algebra it's very useful way to get all possible combinations of a set.

you should also have knowledge in possibilities to solve this problem:

in this set `{1, 2, 6, 10}` element `1` has a **k-Permutations** which is `3`

and this Permutations is : `{2, 1, 6, 10},{6, 2, 1, 10},{10, 2, 6, 1}`.

also element `2` has **k-Permutations** which is `2`

`2` Permutations is : `{1, 6, 2, 10},{1, 10, 6, 2}`.

element `6` has a **k-Permutations** which is `1`

`6` Permutations is : `{1, 2, 10, 6}`.

finally the total possible Permutations for all elements in set : `3 * 2 * 1 = 6`.

simple algorithm to print all possible Permutations:

```
   int[] num = {1,2,6,10}; 
   int[] a = num.clone();
   ArrayList<String> combs = new ArrayList<String>();
   int temp;
    for(int i=0; i < num.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j < num.length; j++){
             temp = a[i];
             a[i] = a[j];
             a[j] = temp;
            String obj = Arrays.toString(a);
            if(!combs.contains(obj)){
               combs.add(obj);
            }
             a = num.clone();  
        }
    }
    System.out.println("All possible order Combinations:");
    for(String obj : combs){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
```

**output:**

```
All possible order Combinations:
[2, 1, 6, 10]
[6, 2, 1, 10]
[10, 2, 6, 1]
[1, 6, 2, 10]
[1, 10, 6, 2]
[1, 2, 10, 6]
```

hope this would help.